# Dwarf Fortress - Haven't Been Attacked

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Okay right, so I'm fairly new to DF but have managed to get a semi-sizeable base up and running with some fortifications and a (I hope) half-decent military. Anyways, we're nearly at the third year and haven't been attacked, raided or besieged and I'm starting to wonder why nothing has come along when I've read that everything is out to kill you! Is there a way to force people to attack you just for the hell of it?

Edit: I just got besieged by goblins, guess they had a bit of a treck and I slaughtered an elven caravan, so lets see what the consequences of that are...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a few reasons why you've not had anyone attack...

Normally attacks occur after your fortress has exceeded a certain value, and if you haven't yet passed this then you won't get many/any attackers. You can try engraving to raise the value of the fort, to cause some attackers to come.

Also, it's possible that the attackers are far far away, this means they'll take longer to get to you, sometimes a number of years can pass without incident, only to suddenly get attacked when you were starting to think there was nothing out there, and you'd recycled those walls to build more bedrooms...

And finally it's possible there isn't anything out there. Sometimes other civilizations will be wiped out, or simply never spawn due to the spawning mechanics (which in turn effects the world generation.)

To see if you've maybe been involved in wars/attacks/other things and not realised (maybe a dog scared off a sneaky goblin you didn't notice?) hit <kbd>C</kbd> and it'll show ANY civ's you've interacted with, be that by wars, or trade (and it'll show the dwarven civ you've come from).

If you're looking for a fight, dig deeper brave dwarf...

Comment: How deep are we talking?

Comment: also, there are elves listed under C how do I force them to attack? (Or should slaughtering their next caravan do the trick?)

Comment: Deeper, dwarf, deeper....

You'll find some fun things on the way too ;)

Comment: Elves hate you using wood, so cut down ALL THE TREES. Also, slaughtering caravans of those tree hugging hippies can't hurt either ;)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a couple simple things to check:

1. It is entirely possible that during world gen all other civilizations have died off. If this is the case, you will never get invaded, etc., though you should still come under fire from Mega and Forgotten Beasts. A subset of this case is embarking on an isolated island or continent -- there might be elves or goblins in the world, they just can't *reach* you. You can check this by viewing the neighbors tab on the embark screen. (Press Tab to change modes)

[image]

(If the neighbors tab only has Dwarves, you will never be invaded / receive traders)

2. You have not met the Wealth Threshold for invasions and/or megabeasts. Just make more stuff, and they will come!
3. Invaders are turned off in the config. Check "d_init.txt" inside /installation_folder/data/init to see what the settings are. There are also "d_init.txt" files within each save directory, so you can tweak these on a game-by-game basis. Depending on where you downloaded the game from, this might have been set to "OFF".
   [image]

Comment: If you want to confirm 1), you can copy+paste the save directory to create a duplicate world, abandon your copied game, and then restart dwarf mode and either navigate to the position of your old fortress, or use the Reclaim functionality to snap to the position. Once there, you can check the Neighbors tab to see who's around.